# Post Via Email to a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, email

I have a scenario where we would like to post to our blog via email. However, it needs to be to a custom post type. I've done a bit of research but haven't found any examples or ideas on how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

When a post is submitted by email and published WordPress Runs an action hook named `'publish_phone'` so you can get the post there and change its type like this:

```
add_action('publish_phone','custom_type_by_mail');
function custom_type_by_mail($post_id){
    $p = get_post($post_id,'ARRAY_A');
    $p['post_type'] = "YOUR_CUSTOM_TYPE_NAME_HERE";
    wp_update_post($p);
}
```

Probably not the smartest way but it does work and its simple.